# xcode retain cycle not show in memory graph

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks, retain-cycle

I'm trying to understand how xcode debugging tool works in terms of detecting retain cycles.
I have a simple Parent and Child view controllers both holds references to each other.
And after executing app opening closing VC several time, when I open debugging tool it neither shows that there is an issue with retain cycle nor runtime issue.
Please find below the code example and attached screenshot of xcode debugging tool

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var child: ChildViewController?

    @IBAction func open(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueChild", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "segueChild") {
             child = segue.destination as? ChildViewController
            child?.parentVC = self
        }
    }
}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
    var parentVC: ViewController?

    @IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image: ChildViewController]

[image: ParentViewController]

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I just asked a scarily similar question. Haha https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988810/xcode-memory-graph-debugger-not-showing-cycles

Comment: @Fogmeister No :), but it is great it is not only me :D

Answer (score -1):

*[EDIT, the real answer]*
I think you're simply misreading the visual debugger. Taking a closer look at your screen captures, those memory diagrams are actually categorized under **Retain Cycles**.

Note however:

To actually waste memory, you'll need to abandon all references to the **parent** `UIViewController`. As long as the parent remains accessible, both parent and child are accessible from somewhere, even though they have a retain cycle.

(If you replace the child VC with a new one, the previous cycle actually broken and **replaced** by a new one. By constantly updating the `child` VC property, you're not wasting anything either.)

Imagine (all arrows are strong):

```
                                    V--------------------
RootWindow --> GrandParentVC --> ParentVC --> ChildVC --^
```

This is not a problem.

Now suppose we replace GrandParentVC. An unreachable cycle is created:

```
RootWindow --> ANewVC

   V--------------------
ParentVC --> ChildVC --^
```

Comment: thanks for answer,
First of all, the project name is ReatinCycle :), that's why it is "categorized under that name". I understand what you mean by "An unreachable cycle is created:" but after changing root view controller to the new one the graph still doesn't show double linked arrows...